Invalid plugin configuration archive
I am upgrading my spring boot application from 1.2.3 to 2.1.0
in the pom file of my application, i am getting "Invalid plugin configuration: archive" filter is not working. here is part of my pom file. 4
<build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/${filter}.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                true
                            </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Filter>${filter}</Filter>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

can anyone please help me in this.

Were you wanting to use <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> for setting the manifest entries instead?
example: Adding properties to manifest file with spring boot
Please note I mean using the jar plugin in addition to spring-boot-maven-plugin

or maven-war-plugin if you are packaging a war

No SPring Boot requires this plugin.

Not sure if I understood.
I didn't mean replace spring-boot-maven-plugin but use maven-jar-plugin as an additional plugin as shown in the example link

No need as that is already configured by the parent.
